# any way to further speed up aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm working on a project that requires aggregation on nested fields.

However, the performance is not that good and the size of the docs exceeds the memory a lot so it could't hold all the field data in the memory.

So I'm now considering to use doc_value, but I'm not sure if:

```
  1) doc_value works for nested fields;
  2) it could really speed up;
  3) any other suggestions?
```

Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: doc_values wont speed up. It actually reduces the speed to some 15% but the system would be highly consistent as we don't have all data in main memory.

Comment: but the thing is the memory couldn't hold all the data into memory(we have more than 300G in the node). So I'm wondering if using fielddata could cause swap.

Comment: I'm using ssd by the way. That's why I'm wondering if I can get better performance or not

Comment: How much main memory are you using per node ?

Comment: 32G in total. 16G for es.